# Why is __attribute__((constructor)) not working in my code when using clang but works fine while using other C compilers?

Tags: c, constructor, clang, destructor, llvm-clang

When I run the following code in mingw64 compiler, it works fine and output shows three lines as expected. But when the same code is run with clang, the constructor and destructor does not work as expected and the output is only one line that is written in main().
This is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void before_main(void) __attribute__((constructor));
void after_main (void) __attribute__((destructor));

int main (void)
{
  printf ("\nInside main ()");
}

void before_main(void)
{
  printf ("\nBefore main()");
}

void after_main(void)
{
  printf ("\nAfter main()\n");
}
```

Note: No compile error is shown in either cases. The program runs without any error.

Comment: Are you sure that `stdout` (which `printf` writes to) will be initialized in your `before_main` function? And that it will still be initialized in the `after_main` function? No you can't be. This is highly implementation-specific and undefined by the C specification.

Comment: On an slightly related note, remember that `stdout` by default is *line-buffered*, that is the output buffer for `stdout` is flushed and actually written on newline. Think a little bit about that and when and where you print your newlines.

Comment: Ok. Thanls for pointing out. But I actually need to run a particular block of code before main. And I seem to find no other way.

Comment: I tried this code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) and while the functions and strings survive, I can't see that `main()` actually jumps to the functions. Strange. I tried both GCC and Clang.

Comment: If you're okay with being non-portable, you can do it like you do now with `__attribute__`. ***But*** you can't use e.g. input or output, and probably other standard functions.

Comment: what is the use then? Also, I tried using it without print but not woking with clang. Is there any other way to initiate variables in c as in cpp and java. Java even has a static block that runs at file load.

Comment: @unwind: `main()` does not call those functions -- the runtime environment calls them beforehand/afterwards.

Comment: @phoenix_sp: How are you verifying that the code is not running? Try aborting the program somehow (e.g. `*(volatile char *)NULL = 0;` or `__builtin_trap()`) to make sure you are not running the code.

Comment: On Godbolt [it runs without a hitch](https://godbolt.org/z/EWxGnf). But for me on WIN10 using clang-cl.exe from Visual Studio, in my case, destructor function is not called? clang-cl is just a compiler, AFAIK the linker used is `Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29112.0` ... Am I wrong? What gives?  I am using VS Code to do the 64-bit build. Have not tried (yet) this from Visual Studio.

Comment: Note that you can work around the issue (and in fact I would prefer this approach since it doesn't rely on compler extensions) by having `main`'s body be `{ before_main(); int r = main2(); after_main(); return r; }` and put your main code into `main2`. And return a value from main2 since it won't have the implicit `return 0;` that main does.